# WPF: Fast clearing a VisualHost with thousands of Children

Tags: wpf, performance, drawing, children, drawingvisual

In a WPF application I'm using a VisualHost with a Children collection. This children collection contains around 10000-30000 DrawingVisuals.

Drawing these DrawingVisuals takes around 600 ms. Thats OK for me, but clearing the Children collection via Clear() takes about 120 ms. That seems to me very slow in comparison to drawing time.

**Has anybody an idea how to speed up clearing a Children collection?**

Answer (score 0):

Skip adding visuals into visual tree altogether and do the rendering in OnRender() perhaps? Here you might find information that can help you tune the performance: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd483292.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I'm not UIElements, that hava a OnRender() Method to override. I'm using StreamGeometries and render them directly into a DrawingContext.